# Why do pixels appear a different size on the same device on these two web pages?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, pixel

I'm making a portfolio for some projects I've worked on whilst learning to code. I've added a banner to the top of each project's webpage, but I'm having issues with a site which is unresponsive (Jubilee Austen page).

Using the Chrome Inspector tool, it says the banner is 55px tall, but it appears smaller than it does on another project page (Rogue Pickings page), where the height of the banner is also 55px. How could this be?

[Jubilee Austen page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqJ8v.png)

[Rogue Pickings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56tPo.png)

Does anyone know how I can fix this so that both banners appear the same height?

Thanks so much in advance!

```css
/* ===== JUBILLEE AUSTEN ===== */

     font-family: atelas;
     src :url('../fonts/atelas/atelas.ttf') format('opentype');
   }


   /* -------- PORTFOLIO BANNER & MANAGEMENT -------- */
   .back {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #1D2120;
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
   }
   .div-link {
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     background-image: url('empty.gif');
   }
   .back-wrap {
     width: 90%;
     margin: auto;
   }
   .chevron {
     margin: 0;
   }
   .chevron img {
     width: 35px;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 1.5%;
   }
   .back-text {
     margin: 0 0 0 3%;
     font-family: atelas;
     font-size: 6em;
     color: #e2e2e2;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 0.8;
     display: none;
   }
   #example {
     clear: both;
     padding-top: 50px;
   }


   /* ======== ORIGINAL CSS ======== */

   /* -------- START OF ORIGINAL CSS -------- */

   body {
     font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
   }

   #about, #work, #contact {
     height: 600px;
   }

   /***** GRID *****/

   .full-width {
     width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   .half-width {
     width: 600px;
     float: left;
   }
   .third-width {
     width: 400px;
     float: left;
   }

   /***** HEADER *****/

   header {
     height: 800px;
     background: url('../img/hero.png');
     background-size: cover;
   }

   header h1 {
     padding: 50px 0;
     font-family: 'Lora', serif;
     font-size: 30px;
     color: #BBC085;
     padding-left: 80px;
   }
   #nav {
     float: right;
     padding: 75px 0;
   }
   nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
   }
   nav ul li a {
     text-transform: uppercase;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 18px;
     color: #828282;
     padding-left: 80px;
   }
   header h2 {
     width: 1000px;
     clear: both;
     font-family: 'Lora', serif;
     font-size: 72px;
     line-height: 80px;
     color: #9a9a9a;
     padding: 20px 0 0 80px;
   }
   header h2 span {
     color: #262a2b
   }

   /***** ABOUT *****/

   #about .full-width {
     padding: 80px 0;
   }

   #about h2 {
     font-family:'Lora', serif;
     font-size: 36px;
   }
   #about p {
     font-size: 21px;
     color: #7F7F7F;
     line-height: 42px;
     padding-right: 50px;
   }

   /***** WORK *****/

   #work {
     background: #F9CEB7;
     text-align: center;
   }

   #work .full-width {
     padding: 115px 0;
   }

   #work img {
     padding-bottom: 30px;
   }

   #work h3 {
     font-size: 24px;
     width: 180px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }

   #work p {
     font-family: 'Lora', serif;
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 30px;
     color: #262a2b;
     padding: 0 35px;
   }

   /**** CONTACT *****/
   #contact {
     background: #EBEBEB;
   }

   #contact .full-width {
     padding: 110px 0;
   }

   #contact img#contact-img {
     border: 16px solid #ffffff;
   }

   #contact h2, #contact #email-header, #contact #socialmedia-header, #contact ul {
     padding-left: 115px;
   }

   #contact #envelope {
     padding: 0 10px 0 115px;
   }

   #contact h2 {
       font-family: 'Lora', serif;
       font-size: 36px;
   }
   #contact #email-header{
       font-size: 32px;
       font-weight: 400;
       margin: -30px 0 5px 0;
   }
   #contact #socialmedia-header {
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 29px;
       margin: 40px 0 0px 0;
   }
   #contact a {
       text-decoration: none;
       color: #C49075;
       font-weight: bold;
       font-size: 28px;
   }

   #contact ul {
     list-style: none;
   }

   #contact ul li {
     display: inline-block;
   }

   #contact ul img {
     font-size: 32px;
     padding-right: 48px;
   }

   /* ======== END ORIGINAL CSS ======== */





   /* TABLET */

   @media all and (min-width: 768px) {

    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 940px) {

      /* -------- PORTFOLIO BANNER CSS -------- */
      .chevron img {
        width: 30px;
      }
      .back-text {
        font-size: 3em;
      }
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- JUBILEE AUSTEN -->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Jubilee Austen | Developer</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

        <!-- FONTS -->
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    </head>

    <body>

      <!-- PORTFOLIO BANNER -->

      <section class="back">
        <a class="div-link" href="../index.html"><span></span></a>
        <div class="back-wrap">
          <figure class="chevron">
            <img src="../img/chevron-b.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-g.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-o.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-r.png" />
          </figure>
          <p class="back-text">back</p>
        </div>
      </section>


      <!-- START OF ORIGINAL BODY -->
      <div id="example">

        <!-- NAV/TITLE PANEL -->
        <header>
          <div class="full width">
            <div class="half-width">
              <h1>Jubilee Austen</h1>
            </div>
        <!-- NAV BAR -->
            <div class="half-width" id="nav">
              <nav>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- <span>Hi,</span> used to change colour of just "Hi," text -->
            <h2><span>Hi,</span> I'm a developer that loves clean & elegant code.</h2>
          </div>
         </header>

         <main>
      <!-- ABOUT PANEL -->
           <section id="about">
             <div class="full-width">
               <h2>A little bit about me.</h2>
               <div class="half-width">
                 <p>I've made my home base in Providence, Rhode Island with my small growing family. My journey into tech started with a degree in journalism. As I started sharing my writing online, I was fascinated with how easily I could get my voice out there. I was hooked and wanted to learn how to build my own site to fit my own specific needs.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="half-width">
                 <p>That curiosity then opened a door that could never be shut. When I learned how to build my first website, I realized I found something that gave me the freedom & versatility I was looking for in my work. Now I've made a full switch to front-end development, where I can use my organization skills and eye for detail to write clean, elegant code.</p>
               </div>
             </div>
           </section>

      <!-- PROCESS PANEL -->
           <section id="work">
             <div class="full-width">
               <div class="third-width">
                 <img src="img/icon-html.png" alt="HTML icon"/>
                 <h3>Hand-Coded HTML</h3>
                 <p>My focus is writing clean, well-formatted, semantic HTML5 by hand to make sure that the content is easy to read, easy to collaborate, trouble-shoot and accessible.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="third-width">
                 <img src="img/icon-css.png" alt="CSS icon"/>
                 <h3>Well-Organized CSS</h3>
                 <p>I pride myself on writing CSS that is easy to read and build on. I focus on keeping my CSS lean and fast to load, and I make it a habit to stay up to date on current best practices.</p>
               </div>
               <div class="third-width">
                 <img src="img/icon-pencil.png" alt="Pencil icon"/>
                 <h3>Easy Converting PSD to HTML</h3>
                 <p>You can trust me to take a designer's PSD and quickly & accurately convert it into a webpage that is pixel-perfect match.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </section>

      <!-- CONTACT PANEL -->
            <footer id="contact">
              <div class="full-width">
                <div class="half-width">
                  <img id="contact-img" src="img/contact.png" alt="Person typing at laptop"/>
                </div>
                <div class="half-width" id="contact-info">
                  <h2>Like what you see?</h2>
                  <h3 id="email-header">Let's meet for a cup of coffee.</h3>
                  <a href="mailto:hi@jubileeausten.com"><img id="envelope" src="img/icon-envelope.png" alt="mail icon"/>hi@jubileeausten.com</a>
                  <h4 id="socialmedia-header">Or, find me on the interwebs</h4>
              <!-- ICON LINKS -->
                  <ul>
                    <li><a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon-twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon-tumblr.png" alt="Tumblr icon"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon-instagram.png" alt="Instagram icon"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon-linkedin.png" alt="Linkedin icon"/></a></li>
                    <li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank"><img src="img/icon-github.png" alt="GitHub icon"/></a></li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </footer>
          </main>

          <!-- END OF ORIGINAL HTML -->

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
/* ===== ROGUE PICKINGS ===== */
 /* =========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */
   @font-face {
     font-family: atelas;
     src :url('../fonts/atelas/atelas.ttf') format('opentype');
   }


   /* -------- PORTFOLIO BANNER & MANAGEMENT -------- */
   .back {
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #1D2120;
     padding: 10px 0;
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
   }
   .div-link {
     position:absolute;
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     top:0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 1;
     background-image: url('empty.gif');
   }
   .back-wrap {
     width: 90%;
     margin: auto;
   }
   .chevron {
     margin: 0;
   }
   .chevron img {
     width: 35px;
     float: left;
     margin-right: 1.5%;
   }
   .back-text {
     margin: 0 0 0 3%;
     font-family: atelas;
     font-size: 6em;
     color: #e2e2e2;
     text-decoration: none;
     line-height: 0.8;
     display: none;
   }
   #example {
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: auto;
     clear: both;
     padding-top: 55px;
   }


   /* ======== ORIGINAL ROGUE PICKINGS CSS ======== */
   html {
     font-size:16px;
   }
   body {
     /*max-width: 1200px; --- REMOVED FOR PORTFOLIO BANNER --- */
     margin: 0 auto;
     font-size: 1em;
     font-family: Montserrat, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   }
   header {
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   .top-section {
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   .bottom-section {
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   footer {
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   header, .top-section, .bottom-section, footer {
     max-width: 90%;
   }
   h1, h3, h4 {
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   h1 {
     color: black;
     font-size: 1.875em;
     text-align: center;
     width: auto;
     padding: 2.45% 0;
   }
   h3 {
     color: black;
     font-size: 1.125em;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 15px;
   }
   h4 {
     color: black;
     font-size: 0.75em;
   }
   .main-title h3 {
     text-align: left;
     padding: 5px 0px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     color:#77a466;
   }


   /*The widths are in a percentage!*/
   header {
     width: 100%;
     height: 10%;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   header .heading {
     border-bottom:3px solid #77a466;
     height: auto;
   }
   header span {
     color: #77a466;
   }
   header nav {
     padding: 8% 0px;
     margin:auto;
     }
   header nav a {
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 0.875em;
     padding: 0 10px 20px 10px;
     color:#77a466;
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     }
     #last-nav {
       padding: 0 10px;
     }

   /*The widths are in a percentage!*/
   .top-section, .bottom-section {
     width: 100%;
     margin: 0 auto;
     clear: both;
   }
   .main-image {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     float: left;
     clear: both;
   }
   .main-image img {
     width: 100%;
     border-bottom:3px solid #77a466;
     border-top: 3px solid #77a466;
   }
   .main-title {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     float: left;
   }
   .main-title p {
     padding: 0px;
     line-height: 156.25%;
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   .section-one, .section-two, .section-three {
     width: 100%;
     height: auto;
     clear: both;
     border-top: 1px solid #eee;
   }
   .section-one h4, .section-two h4, .section-three h4 {
     padding: 10px 30px 10px 0px;
   }
   .menu {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
   }
   .menu li {
     padding: 10px 0;
     color:#77a466;
   }
   .reviews {
     color: #333;
     line-height: 135%;
     font-size: 1em;
   }
   .address {
     font-size: 1em;
     line-height: 150%;
   }
   .reviews, .address {
     padding: 0px 30px 0px 0px;
   }

   /*The widths are in a percentage!*/
   footer {
     width: 100%;
     height: 50px;
     border-top:3px solid #eee;
     margin: 0 auto;
     clear: both;
     text-align: center;
   }
   footer span {
     font-family: "Wisdom Script", script;
     text-transform: lowercase;
     color: #77a466;
     font-size: 0.875;
   }




   @media all and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 939px) {
     header nav {
       padding: 3.75% 0px;
     }
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 940px) {

      /* -------- PORTFOLIO BANNER CSS -------- */
      .chevron img {
        width: 30px;
      }
      .back-text {
        font-size: 3em;
      }
      #example {
        width: 96%;
        padding: 40px 2% 0 2%;
      }

      /* -------- ORIGINAL CSS -------- */
      body {
        /*width: 96%;   --- REMOVED FOR PORTFOLIO BANNER --- */
        /*padding: 0 2%;   --- REMOVED FOR PORTFOLIO BANNER --- */
      }
      header, .top-section, .bottom-section, footer {
        max-width: 100%;
      }
      header h1 {
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
      }
      header {
        height: 100px;
      }
      header .heading {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
      header nav {
        float: right;
        width: auto;
        padding: 45px 0px;
      }
      header nav a {
        display: inline;
      }
      .section-one, .section-two {
        border-right: 1px solid #eee
      }
      .section-one h4 {
        padding: 10px 0px;
      }
      .section-two h4, .section-three h4 {
        padding: 10px 30px;
      }
      .menu {
        padding: 0px;
      }
      .reviews, .address {
        padding: 0px 30px;
      }
      .section-one, .section-two, .section-three {
        width: 33%;
        height: auto;
        clear: none;
        float: left;
        border-top: 1px solid #eee;
      }
    }
    /* -------- END ORIGINAL CSS -------- */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!-- ROGUE PICKINGS -->
<html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <title>Rogue Pickings</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    </head>


    <body>

  <!-- PORTFOLIO BANNER -->

      <section class="back">
        <a class="div-link" href="../index.html"><span></span></a>
        <div class="back-wrap">
          <figure class="chevron">
            <img src="../img/chevron-b.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-g.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-o.png" />
            <img src="../img/chevron-r.png" />
          </figure>
          <p class="back-text">back</p>
        </div>
      </section>



  <!-- START OF ORIGINAL BODY -->
      <div id="example">

        <!-- MODULE: Logo & Nav -->
        <header>
          <div class="heading">
            <h1><span>rogue</span> pickings</h1>
          </div>
          <nav>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#menu">Menu</a>
            <a href="">Locations</a>
            <a href="">Gallery</a>
            <a href="#reviews">Reviews</a>
            <a id="last-nav" href="#contact">Contact</a>
          </nav>
        </header>

        <!-- MODULE: Top Section -->
        <div class="top-section">
          <div class="main-image"><img src="img/download.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="main-title" id="about">
            <h3>Welcome to our little corner of the internet!</h3>
            <p>Welcome to Rogue Pickings, the roaming truck bringing you the freshest ingredients and ideas in food. Our team works hard so you can be sure our ingredients are always fresh and picked carefully. Our menu changes every day and is made with you in mind. We can't wait to come to you! Check out our locations to see where you can find us. </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- MODULE: Bottom Section -->
        <div class="bottom-section">
          <div class="section-one" id="menu"><h4>Today's Specials</h4>
            <ul class="menu">
              <li>Flaming Hummus & Falafel Salad</li>
              <li>Sizzling Bean Burrito</li>
              <li>Green Gloves Tamales</li>
            </ul>
          </div>

          <div class="section-two" id="reviews"><h4>Our Awesome Reviews</h4>
            <p class="reviews">"I got so excited about the yumminess of the falafel salad that I am typing this review as I inhale my lunch. Yes it is that good.... Service was super friendly and quick. Can't wait see you Rogue Pickings again tomorrow!"</p>
          </div>
          <div class="section-three" id=contact><h4>Contact</h4>
            <p class="address">1001 Potrero Avenue<br>
              San Francisco, CA 94110<br>
              (415) 206-8000 </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- MODULE: Footer -->
        <footer>
          <h4>Powered by lots of <span>fresh</span> ingredients.</h4>
        </footer>

        <!-- END OF ORIGINAL ROGUE PICKINGS HTML -->

      </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: iPhone is scaling the content if you don't include special meta tag to prevent it from doing that. Most likely banner is 55px in the second screenshot and appears smaller on the first. 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">

Comment: would you share your code!

Comment: The widths of the banners in the screenshots are not the same, so I think @LukaszMuzyka has the right answer.

Comment: @MrLister ha!, feels like a competition :P

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have now shared the code.

Comment: Thanks @LukaszMuzyka I had <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> on both pages before and have now added maximum-scale=1.0 but there has not been a change

Answer (score 0):

Your banner is not responsive, its height is fixed (55px). If the site is being displayed differently - different viewport zoom, your banner will seems to be smaller/larger.

Check the viewport meta tag in those sites:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

If the `initial-scale` is different or if one of the pages is missing the viewport tag it can explain the differences.

As mentioned before, the zoom affects the presented width and this affects the visual size of your banner. If you want it to be responsive, you should change the height units into percentage instead of pixels.

**EDIT**

The first page is much wider than the second, when you zoom out to see all the page it changes the visual height of your banner.

Comment: Thanks. How come the two webpages with the same code appear different heights on the same device?

Comment: Thanks @MrLister I have now shared the code. Both HTML files have that meta tag... the confusion builds!

Comment: @MrLister Yes, the banner appears to scale down when reducing the page size from 1200px downwards. I am confused as to why it does this on the Jubilee Austen page but not the Rogue Pickings page. It should have a fixed height the whole time, which changes to a smaller fixed height with the desktop media query at min-width: 940px.

Comment: If your screen present more pixels then obviously, each pixel will look smaller.

Answer (score 0):

i cant remember if zoom level is persistant on an iphone but it is on desktop browsers, could you have zoomed in/out of one of them? is there a way of making sure you are at 100% zoom?

Edit

is the smaller one contained in a set of tags that is smaller than 55px? as that would cause it to be restricted to the smaller size

Comment: Both are at 75% zoom.